# Trying to create a simple time and date program, having problems with usage of .upper()

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

user_input = input("Would you like to know the date and time today?").upper()


if user_input == "YES":
    print "The date and time is: " + "%s/%s/%s - %s:%s:%s" % (now.day, now.month,     now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

I'm attempting to get user_input to become all uppercase so I don't have to include code such as:

```
if user_input == "yes" or "YES" or "YeS" ... etc.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what is your problem statement? What is the value of `user_input` after your `input` statement?

Comment: Would you like to know the date and time today?yes
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Time_and_Date.py", line 4, in <module>
        user_input = input("Would you like to know the date and time today?").upper()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined\          thats what happens when I type in yes as the input...

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Python 2 and Python 3. Change your `input` to [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). `input` is for Python 3.

If you want to use Python 3, you need to change your [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) statement at the end to be a [function call](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function):

```
print("The date and time is: " + "%s/%s/%s - %s:%s:%s" % (now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
```

If you want to use Python 2, changing `input` to `raw_input` is sufficient.

To determine which version you are running, execute this command from your console:

```
python --version
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can check which one I am using? Also, what part of it is in python 2 and what part is in 3?

Comment: I've modified my answer to provide more details